# Determine if client supports byte range requests?

Tags: http

Are there any elegant solutions to determine if a *client* supports byte range requests for video?

On iOS- the initial request for a video for example will make a request of range 0-1, so at least on iOS it could be relied upon definitively.

Are there other alternatives for other clients?

Answer (score 0):

It is more usual for the client to test whether or not the server supports ranges, which is what iOS appears to be attempting in your example.

I think that the answer to your question is that the client supports Ranges if it ever sends a range request (ie. the Range header is present and not empty). The caveat here is of course that a client may support ranges but choose never to send a Range header to the server in which case the server cannot know.

All that said, I would have to question what use is it to the server to know if a client supports Ranges. If the client does not request a Range then the server should not send a Range. Likewise if the client requests a Range then the server should respond with that Range (assuming it supports Ranges)

For more information you should check out [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

Comment: Waiting for something to "ever" happen, unfortunately, does not really give a definitive answer (i.e. if a client never sends a range request- does that mean it doesn't support it? Of course not).

In my particular use case, it is useful for the server to know, at least at the time of first response, whether a client supports Ranges. Otherwise- why would I ask the question? :P

Excuse the snarkiness, I do sincerely appreciate your taking the time to provide some thoughts on the matter.